# How do you refute these conjectures that seem imply contradictory statements?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, conjectures

I've formulated two conjectures that seems to imply a strong result when are combined with well known equivalences of the Riemann hypothesis, and I would like to know how get a disproof of such statements.

Let $S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\text{n mod k}$ **the sum of remainder function**, then it is know that for each $n>1$
$$\sigma(n)+S(n)=S(n-1)+2n-1,$$
where $\sigma(n)$ is the **sum of divisors function,** and let $H_n=1+1/2+\ldots+1/n$ the **nth harmonic number**.

> **Conjecture 1.** The following asymptotic equivalence holds 
>   $$\frac{S(n)}{e^{H_n}}\sim\frac{n}{10},$$
>   as $n\to\infty$.

**On assumption of this Conjecture 1** one has that using **Robin's criterion** for the Riemann's hypothesis (or also **Lagarias equivalence**, the computations are the same), $\forall n>5040$
$$\sigma(n)<e^\gamma n\log\log n$$
can be evaluated as 
$$\frac{S(n-1)}{e^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{H_{n-1}}}+\frac{2n}{ne^\gamma e^{O(\frac{1}{n})}}<\frac{1}{e^{H_{n}}}+\frac{S(n)}{e^{H_{n}}}+\frac{e^\gamma n\log\log n}{ne^\gamma e^{O(\frac{1}{n})}},$$
since $H_n=\log n+\gamma+O(\frac{1}{n})$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant, thus $LHS\sim\frac{n-1}{10}+\frac{2}{e^\gamma}$ and by comparison with $RHS\sim\frac{n}{10}+\log\log n$ one conclude this equivalence with Riemann hypothesis holds asymptotically.

On the other hand, one has for $M(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(k)$ is the **Mertens function**, where $\mu(k)$ is **Mobius function**, then

> **Conjecture 2.** The following holds 
>   $$(M(n))^2=o\left(e^{H_n}\right)$$
>   as $n\to\infty$.

Thus by comparison with the equivalence of Riemann hypothesis stated as $M(x)=O(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}),\forall\epsilon>0$, on assumption of this **Conjecture 2** one get a contradiction since there is a constant $C>0$ such that 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(M(n))^2}{e^{H_n}}$ is computed as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{C\cdot n^{2(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon)}}{ne^\gamma e^{O(\frac{1}{n})}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{Cn^{2\epsilon}}{e^\gamma}$$
that is infnite for any $\epsilon>0$, a contradiction with the assumption that $(M(n))^2=o\left(e^{H_n}\right)$ that means $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(M(n))^2}{e^{H_n}}=0$.

I did graphs of such ratios, but I'm assuming that perhaps there are mistakes in my computations or facts that I don't understand, since I understand that my reasoning are very soft for such great unsolved problem. I would like to ask how can we refute these conjectures.

> **Question.** Can you refute each of these conjecture? **Then I can learn how you give a mathematical reasoning for my question. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conjecture 2 is false. Since $H_n = \log n + \gamma + O(1/n)$, we have that $e^{H_n} = e^{\gamma} n + O(1)$, and so your conjecture $M(n)^2 = o(e^{H_n})$ is equivalent to $M(x) = o(\sqrt{x})$, which is well known to be false.

Comment: Very thanks much @PeterHumphries I choose close the question, I say choose an aswer since I believe that since $S(n)=O(n^2)$ then Conjecture 1 also is false.. Very thanks much,

Comment: @user243301 : if $M(x) = o(x^a)$  then because $1/\zeta(s) = s \int_1^\infty M(x) x^{-s-1} dx$ is meromorphic (hence its poles are at least of order $1$ ) if $1/\zeta(s)$ had a pole at $s=\rho$ of order $1$ then $M(x) =  \frac{x^{\rho}}{\zeta'(\rho) } + \ldots$  which implies $Re(\rho) < a$, but we know there are poles such that $Re(\rho) = 1/2$ hence $M(x) \ne o(x^{1/2})$

Comment: Very thanks much for the explanation, Best wishes this week @user1952009